# "call injustice" or "call it injustice"?

Tags: grammar

It is from [Crash Coursd US history](https://youtu.be/9C72ISMF_D0). It is at around 8 minute and 25 second. The context is the host dosn't get a question right and he says:

> It is ridiculous. I **call injustice**.

Why didn't he say *I call it injustice*?

Comment: In the written form, I think that needs to be: *I call 'injustice'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "call" something in this context is a shortening of "called out", and means to speak out and say that something is wrong, or someone has done something wrong.

For example:

> Dave Kitson called out by Leroy Rosenior over Raheem Sterling racism comments
>   <sub>(newpaper headline)</sub>

Your example of "I call injustice" means that the speaker/writer is *declaring* injustice has taken place.